# Oracle Proc to SQL Reporting Services: character set name is not recognized

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, oracle, reporting-services

A few months ago Oracle queries stopped working on our reporting services server after a service pack on the reporting server.  I ended up having to grant permissions on Oracle directories to eliminate the first error and then renamed the NLS_LANG registry entry (effectively deleting it) to get rid of the second error.  The old value was: AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252

Now we are moving some new reports into production which use Oracle stored procedures and they are getting this error.

```
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
w3wp!processing!8!7/27/2009-09:26:09:: e ERROR: An exception has occurred in data source 'CSUD3_RPTAPL'. Details: Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: Query execution failed for data set 'MYDATASET'. ---> System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 57:
PLS-00553: character set name is not recognized
ORA-06550: line 0, column 0:
PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
```

I've created a test procedure that simply returns

```
select 'test' "field1" from dual;
```

It gets the same error.  Tonight I will try setting NLS_LANG back to it's old value and see if that fixes the procedures - although it will break the regular oracle reports.  If anyone has a clue what is going on, please enlighten me.

From what I've read, the client should be using the database default if the charset is not specified on the client.

Comment: You mention an "old" NLS_LANG value.  That seems to imply that there is a different "new" NLS_LANG value-- what is that new value?

Comment: The new value is nothing - I renamed the registry key.  This means the client should use the server setting.  This was to fix an error were getting.

Comment: What were the errors you got after the service pack ? you mention that Oracle "stopped working", does it mean that the database failed to start?. Did you remove the NLS_LANG parameter on the server or on the client ?

Comment: I fixed that first sentence which was unclear.  The reports using oracle on reporting services stopped working.  We removed the NLS_LANG on the client to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key was the first error message:

ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified.

Which led to this:

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12705_error.htm

And then a closer examination of the folder permissions.  I needed to grant perms to authenticated users on the ORACLE_HOME directory and subdirs.

Working now!